# Convert this specific mysql bd class to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, class, mysqli

Can you please help me to fully convert this class to work with mysqli?
It's a class working on an old system, I just want to make it work with mysqli without having to modify the existing code on all the system.

I tried but with no success.

Thanks in advance!

```
class BD {

    var $sServidor = "host";
    var $sBaseDeDatos = "DB";
    var $sUsuario = "user";
    var $sClave = "pass";

    function Conectar() {
        if (($this->sServidor != "") && ($this->sUsuario != "")) {
            $this->oConexion = mysql_connect($this->sServidor, $this->sUsuario, $this->sClave);
            mysql_select_db($this->sBaseDeDatos, $this->oConexion);
            mysql_set_charset("utf8", $this->oConexion);
        }
    }

    function RetornarConexion() {
        return $this->oConexion;
    }

    function Seleccionar($pSQL, $pRetornarFila = false) {
        $oResultado = $this->Ejecutar($pSQL);
        return (($pRetornarFila) ? $this->RetornarFila($oResultado) : $oResultado);
    }

    function RetornarFila($pResultado) {
        return mysql_fetch_array($pResultado);
    }

    function ContarFilas($pResultado) {
        $lFilas = 0;
        if ($pResultado) {
            $lFilas = mysql_num_rows($pResultado);
        }
        return $lFilas;
    }

    function Ejecutar($pSQL) {
        $this->Conectar();
        $oResultado = mysql_query($pSQL, $this->oConexion);
        if ($oResultado) {
            if (strpos(strtoupper($pSQL), "INSERT INTO") !== false) {
                $oResultado = mysql_insert_id();
            } else if (strpos(strtoupper($pSQL), "UPDATE") !== false) {
                $oResultado = mysql_affected_rows();
            }
        }
        return $oResultado;
    }

    function RetornarTipo($pResultado, $pCampo) {
        $sTipo = "";
        if ($pResultado) {
            $sTipo = mysql_field_type($pResultado, $pCampo);
        }
        return $sTipo;
    }

    function RetornarLongitud($pResultado, $pCampo) {
        $lLongitud = 0;
        if ($pResultado) {
            $lLongitud = mysql_field_len($pResultado, $pCampo);
        }
        return $lLongitud;
    }

    function Desconectar() {
        mysql_close($this->oConexion);
    }

}
```

Comment: so convert it .. what is the issue?

Comment: That I'm getting a little complicated to make the mysql_fetch_array part work

Comment: It's just `mysqli_fetch_array()`, used exactly the same as `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: You can use https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim

Comment: But when it doesn't works with `function Seleccionar` if i set `$pRetornarFila` to true

Comment: The `$pRetornarFila` It's make to return just 1 specific field from the DB

Comment: @UlisesLz just look up the docs, but most of them is simple as adding an `i`

Comment: Okey i'll keep reading and trying. Maybe being asleep is not helping. Thx. When i fixed i will post my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Okay I'm testing it and think it works okay. Here's the code:
P / D: Sorry for wasting your time. Conclusion: I have to sleep a few more hours per day. Thanks and sorry again.

```
class BD {

var $sServidor = "host";
var $sBaseDeDatos = "DB";
var $sUsuario = "user";
var $sClave = "pass";

    function Conectar() {
        if (($this->sServidor != "") && ($this->sUsuario != "")) {
            $this->oConexion = mysqli_connect($this->sServidor, $this->sUsuario, $this->sClave);
            mysqli_select_db($this->oConexion, $this->sBaseDeDatos);
            mysqli_set_charset($this->oConexion, "utf8");
        }
    }

    function RetornarConexion() {
        return $this->oConexion;
    }

    function Seleccionar($pSQL, $pRetornarFila = false) {
        $oResultado = $this->Ejecutar($pSQL);
        return (($pRetornarFila) ? $this->RetornarFila($oResultado) : $oResultado);
    }

    function RetornarFila($pResultado) {
        return mysqli_fetch_array($pResultado);
    }

    function ContarFilas($pResultado) {
        $lFilas = 0;
        if ($pResultado) {
            $lFilas = mysqli_num_rows($pResultado);
        }
        return $lFilas;
    }

    function Ejecutar($pSQL) {
        $this->Conectar();
        $oResultado = mysqli_query($this->oConexion, $pSQL);
        if ($oResultado) {
            if (strpos(strtoupper($pSQL), "INSERT INTO") !== false) {
                $oResultado = mysqli_insert_id($this->oConexion);
            } else if (strpos(strtoupper($pSQL), "UPDATE") !== false) {
                $oResultado = mysqli_affected_rows($this->oConexion);
            }
        }
        return $oResultado;
    }

    function RetornarTipo($pResultado, $pCampo) {
        $sTipo = "";
        if ($pResultado) {
            $sTipo = mysqli_field_type($pResultado, $pCampo);
        }
        return $sTipo;
    }

    function RetornarLongitud($pResultado, $pCampo) {
        $lLongitud = 0;
        if ($pResultado) {
            $lLongitud = mysqli_field_len($pResultado, $pCampo);
        }
        return $lLongitud;
    }

    function Desconectar() {
        mysqli_close($this->oConexion);
    }

}
```